# How to have one CloudFormation stack import and refer to the latest version of a resource on another stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I have a nested AWS SAM template and the issue is occurring when there is an export-import relation between two stacks for a resource. When the stack which has the exportable resource is modified and deployed, the stack importing it doesn't refer to the newer version of the exported modified resource.

Any way to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options here I would think

And to easy, I name Stack A and Stack B which B depends on an exported resource from stack A

1. If you are using a pipeline for deployment such as Jenkins or AWS Code Pipeline, you can have a step in the pipeline to update stack B after stack A.
2. If not, configure SNS notification for stack A, so SNS can capture stack A events and then from SNS you can trigger Lambda to trigger stack B update.

Comment: point 1 sounds practical... Do you have any was documentation link that would provide the right direction to go in with point 1?

Comment: What are you using now for the pipeline?

Comment: CodePipeline it is

Comment: So that is so simple then https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html

Comment: Maybe but it's not quite evident in the link you shared. That's the Hello World of CodePipeline. Is there an article which tells you how to update stacks in CodePipeline?

Comment: Actually if you go through that one you can find information, anyway https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CloudFormation.html